# Excessive brake pedal travel

Tags: honda, brakes, accord

I have a 2009 Honda Accord, and I can press the brakes 3/4 of the way down before they start braking the vehicle.

I bled brakes at all 4 wheels but it barely made a difference.  One accord owner told me this is normal (excess travel), but it doesn't seem right to me.  (I am repairing this vehicle for a friend).  Inside and outside pads on all 4 wheels are wearing evenly.

Is there a known issue with the Accords of this age?  I don't want to start replacing calipers, nor the master cylinder, without some idea what I'm looking for.  I can test calipers slide easily on pins (but since inner and outer pads are wearing evenly I don't think that's it).  I suppose pistons could be sticking - not sure how to test what is beyond normal.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Brake flushing/bleeding procedures are always done with engine off, eliminating power vacuum brake boost unit  from interference.  You'll  feel only the hydraulic system pressure as a firm pedal a third of way down.  Every car/truck/suv without the engine running; pressing the brake pedal several times will deplete reserve vacuum until  pedal firms up to less than half travel. With engine idling, the brake boost unit multiplies hydraulic pressures; the pedal feels mushy but considered normal in everyday braking as power assisted brakes can lock up without abs.

Comment: I bled the system with engine off.  Fluid was original (13 yr old) and needed flush.  But there is still way to much travel.

Comment: With four disc brakes, calipers and pads have very little piston travel by relying on the piston seals to retract pads slightly with slight drag on rotors. This translates to less brake pedal travel after finalizing brake flush/bleeding procedures. The calipers, pistons, piston seals, rotors and pads must be clean and free of corrosion and all in alignment to minimize extra pedal travel from misalignment of parts due to wear and tear. If parts are in alignment, hydraulic pressure from pedal travel should result in less than half travel for a firm pedal.